# stacked box2d objects starting jittering

Tags: c++, box2d

I want to write a game where at startup blocks are ordered like this:
[image: http://www.powerframeworks.com/series/HI/006/hi006_0606_v2.jpg]

but when I do it in box2d the bodies just start moving and falling from the ground.
how can I do it so bodies start sleeping and not falling from the ground?
Thanks

Comment: How about you post your code? Or do you want us to imagine how we can help you? Physics sims (especially stacking ones) usually need tuning of parameters.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Given the library this is a valid question. The answer doesn't require code, but advice for library settings.

Answer (score 0):

The Box2D Testbed Pyramid test (which comes the with Box2D distribution) stacks bodies in a pyramid shape that go to sleep (like you're asking for). You can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/Testbed/Tests/Pyramid.h) to see how this gets done.

From a library settings perspective:

1. Create a world with a negative y gravity.
2. Create a static ground body with a flat topped shape (like an edge shape in the horizontal direction).
3. Create block-shaped non-zero-density dynamic bodies positioned so they are above the ground and stack per the shape of the pyramid that you want.

Be sure to use dimensions and locations for your ground and block shapes that are within the Box2D recommended range. Also, beware that if you position the blocks with too little space between the vertices you use, that the simulation will actually push them apart a small bit (this is related to the `b2_linearSlop` compile-time setting).